# Weird python docstring interaction with Jupyter Lab's "contextual help"

Tags: python, jupyter-lab

I came across an extremely weird phenomenon. I use Jupyter Lab's contextual help quite a lot like this: [image]

There are 2 tabs, 1 tab for the main working area, and 1 for the contextual help. I have problems with displaying docstrings correctly on it. My code looks like this:

[image]

The class `Callbacks` is sort of long, so I break those up into multiple cells all the time. The idea is, I can define a class, with basic functionality. Then I add instance methods to the class bit by bit. Cell 2 shows the docs with `help()`, which works fine, but for some reason, the contextual help looks like this:

[image]

No docstring values so far. After cell 3 has been executed, it looks like this:

[image]

For some reason, it now has the docstring field. So what is going on? And how can I make the docstring field appear just after cell 1?

Comment: Your indentation looks wrong. `def _withInspectLoss` needs to be indented inside `class Callbacks`

Comment: @Barmar Please reread it. I specifically do that so I can split the definition up in multiple sections

Comment: I *think* that this is not specific to JupyterLab, but instead to how ipykernel generates the `inspect_request` response, which in turn is done by IPython's `object_inspect_mime` which is implemented as a part of [interactiveshell](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/5da6784b690b085bd9cde88e08ab4e2def9f65ff/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py). You should probably try to reproduce the issue at this level and report to IPython developers and work with them to fix it (if it indeed is there).